# Is the intersection of a decreasing (w.r.t. inclusion) sequence of cofinal subsets again a cofinal subset?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, nets

Let $(D, \le )$ be a directed set. A subset $A$ of $D$ is cofinal in $D$ if and only if $\forall d \in D, \exists a\in A, d \le a$. Let $(D_n)$ be a decreasing (w.r.t. inclusion) sequence of cofinal subsets of $D$.

> Is it true that $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} D_n$ is cofinal in $D$?

Comment: There's is such an obvious counterexample, that I'm scared of bringing it up, since you might smack your forehead so hard, you'd get a concussion. :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila Knowing that the answer is affirmative or negative is already enough for me :v

Comment: What if the intersection is empty?

Comment: That will give you a counter example

Comment: @Logic One example with an empty intersection has $D=\mathbb{N}$ and $D_n=\{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m \ge n\}$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I was trying to give the OP a hint :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Geoffrey Trang pointed in a comment, such intersection could be an empty set. For example, $D=\mathbb{N}$ and $D_n=\{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m \ge n\}$.